# how can i fixed the error of the assigned id that has never been used but actually used?

Tags: vue.js, axios, dollar-sign, editmode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8gBm.png)

screenshot of my code. the error there is the id is not used even I already used it.

I watch a video and copy it but in the part of my axios, the todoUrl and id has a problem.
the video link is this.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQQXlavDDc8

Comment: I guess it could be wrong type of string deceleration your using a back-tick  to call the variable try example: ` `${id}` `  instead of ` '${id}' `

Answer (score 0):

It's not a string but a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
await Axios.put(`${todoUrl}/${id}`, this.todoItem);
...
await Axios.delete(`${todoUrl}/${id}`, this.todoItem);
```

Wrap your code with backtick symbol `` ` `` instead of `'` single quote